# adding a multi select on js datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to implement the select filter using demo code provided, but it does not filter the table.

**JS CODE**

```
imsi_table = $('#imsi_table').DataTable({
                        "lengthMenu": [[7,-1],['Per Site','All']],
                        "iDisplayLength": 7,
                        "ordering": false,
                         "bLengthChange": true,
                         "bInfo": false,
                         "bFilter": false,
                         fixedHeader: {
                                header: true,
                                footer: true
                            },
                         "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
                             var api = this.api(), data;

                            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
                                var intVal = function ( i ) {
                                    return typeof i === 'string' ?
                                        i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                                        typeof i === 'number' ?
                                            i : 0;
                                };

                             // Total over this page
                                postPayTotal = api
                                    .column( 2, { page: 'current'} )
                                    .data()
                                    .reduce( function (a, b) {
                                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                                    }, 0 );

                             // Update footer
                                $( api.column( 2 ).footer() ).html(
                                    postPayTotal
                                );

                            // Total over this page
                                prePayTotal = api
                                    .column( 3, { page: 'current'} )
                                    .data()
                                    .reduce( function (a, b) {
                                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                                    }, 0 );

                             // Update footer
                                $( api.column( 3 ).footer() ).html(
                                        prePayTotal
                                );

                             // Total over this page
                                uknownTotal = api
                                    .column( 4, { page: 'current'} )
                                    .data()
                                    .reduce( function (a, b) {
                                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                                    }, 0 );

                             // Update footer
                                $( api.column( 4 ).footer() ).html(
                                        uknownTotal
                                );

                         },
                         initComplete: function () {
                               this.api().columns('.multi-select-filter').every( function () {
                                   var column = this;
                                   console.log(column);
                                   var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                                       .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                                       .on( 'change', function () {
                                           var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                               $(this).val()
                                           );

                                           column
                                               .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                                               .draw();
                                           console.log(val);
                                       } );

                                   column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                                       select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                                   } );
                               } );
                           }
                    }); // datatble end
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="imsi_table_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline dt-bootstrap">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="dataTables_length" id="imsi_table_length">
            <label>Show
                <select name="imsi_table_length" aria-controls="imsi_table" class="form-control input-sm">
                    <option value="7">Per Site</option>
                    <option value="-1">All</option>
                </select>
                entries</label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <table id="imsi_table" class="table table-bordered table-inverse table-hover table-striped table-sm dataTable" role="grid">
            <thead class="">
                <tr role="row">
                    <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 374px;">Site</th>
                    <th class="multi-select-filter sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 188px;">Service</th>
                    <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 182px;">PostPay</th>
                    <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 161px;">PrePay</th>
                    <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 179px;">Uknown</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>


            <tbody>
                <tr role="row" class="odd">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2G Voice</td>
                    <td>1839</td>
                    <td>575</td>
                    <td>583</td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row" class="even">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>3G Voice</td>
                    <td>12311</td>
                    <td>563</td>
                    <td>943</td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row" class="odd">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2G SMS</td>
                    <td>618</td>
                    <td>321</td>
                    <td>239</td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row" class="even">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>3G SMS</td>
                    <td>2849</td>
                    <td>400</td>
                    <td>358</td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row" class="odd">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2G Data</td>
                    <td>1765</td>
                    <td>96</td>
                    <td>3177</td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row" class="even">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>3G Data</td>
                    <td>14345</td>
                    <td>892</td>
                    <td>2260</td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row" class="odd">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>4G</td>
                    <td>1390</td>
                    <td>52</td>
                    <td>151</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Total Unique IMSIs</th>
                    <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                        <select>
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="2G Data">2G Data</option>
                            <option value="2G SMS">2G SMS</option>
                            <option value="2G Voice">2G Voice</option>
                            <option value="3G Data">3G Data</option>
                            <option value="3G SMS">3G SMS</option>
                            <option value="3G Voice">3G Voice</option>
                            <option value="4G">4G</option>
                        </select></th>
                    <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">35117</th>
                    <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">2899</th>
                    <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">7711</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="imsi_table_paginate">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="paginate_button previous disabled" id="imsi_table_previous"><a href="#" aria-controls="imsi_table" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0">Previous</a></li>
                <li class="paginate_button active"><a href="#" aria-controls="imsi_table" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a></li>
                <li class="paginate_button next disabled" id="imsi_table_next"><a href="#" aria-controls="imsi_table" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">Next</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialize your tabla, these indicating `"bFilter": false`. This option does not allow search your table.

Change the option:

```
$('#imsi_table').DataTable({"bFilter": true});
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/39/

Check the reference of DataTable:

http://legacy.datatables.net/ref